# back-side of View in FrameLayout make clickable

Tags: android

I make parallax-effect example app, like google-play.

```xml
<FrameLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/headerImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:clickable="true"/>

  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:clickable="false"/>

  <include
    layout="@layout/common_toolbar"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

My Layout's layer is like below

```
front side
        --- : ToolBar, 
----------- : RecyclerView, scrolling normally, padding dynamically as header height 
    ------- : header image, scrolling slowly
back side
```

parallax effect is working, but I want to make header clickable,
but I couldn't, because header behind RecyclerView.

How can I make this header clickable?

### Edit

simple example app pushed below repos.

https://github.com/sis-yoshiday/ParallaxExample

Comment: why you not make your framelayout clickable

Comment: for image view you can use frame layout properties like android:foreground your image

Comment: @DanialHussain I try my root FrameLayout clickable="true|false", but not work.